# Win Rate calculation - Php and api from leaguepedia

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api

i'm using the api from leaguepedia to receive the informations.

So I  have this code to show how many times a champion was picked in a tournament, its working fine, but
right now im trying to show the winrate and i'm having problems,

for example :

Syndra picked 4 Times - Won 3 times - winrate = 75%, thats the result i expect;

Gragas picked 3 Times - Won 3 times - winrate = 100%, thats the result i expect;

what im recieving is :

Syndra picked 4 Times - Won 1 time - winrate = 25%

Gragas picked 3 Times - Won 1 time - winrate = 33,33% , victory is showing 1 for every champion (image)

i know that my problem might be on the "switch / case", but i don't know how to fix

so how can i fix my code to show the properly win rate.

thanks

thats my code

```
<?php

// $Result is a CURL coming from leaguepedia api
$result = json_decode($file_contents);
$heroPicks = [];
$heroVictory = [];

// Double foreach to access the values from leaguepedia api

foreach ($result as $d) {
    foreach ($d as $data) {
        //$data->title->Team1Picks and 

        // $data->title->Team2Picks  is coming from leaguepedia api 
        //as a string separated by "," Ex:("Gragas,Shen,Maokai,etc")
        // So i need to explode and merge to an array to count.
        $picks1 = explode(",", $data->title->Team1Picks);
        $picks2 = explode(",", $data->title->Team2Picks);

        $picks = array_merge($picks1, $picks2);

        // this switch is to check if 

        // $data->title->Winner == 1 , it means that 
        //  $picks1 won the game else == 2 $picks2 
        // won the game ($data->title->Winner is coming from api aswell)
        switch ($data->title->Winner) {
            case 1:
                $w = $picks1;
                break;

            case 2:
                $w = $picks2;
                break;
        }
        //foreach to count the times a champion was picked
        foreach ($picks as $pick) {
            $pick = trim($pick);
            if (!array_key_exists($pick, $heroPicks)) {
                $heroPicks[$pick] = 0;
            }
            $heroPicks[$pick] += 1;
        }
        //foreach to count how many times a champion won a game
        foreach ($w as $victory) {
            $victory = trim($victory);
            if (!array_key_exists($victory, $heroVictory)) {
                $heroVictory[$victory] = 0;
            }
            $heroVictory[$victory] += 1;
        }
    }
}
//sorting the arrays
uasort(
    $heroPicks,
    function ($a, $b) {
        return $a - $b;
    }
);


uasort(
    $heroVictory,
    function ($c, $d) {
        return $c - $d;
    }
);


$heroPicks = array_reverse($heroPicks);
$heroVictory = array_reverse($heroVictory);

//foreach to show the results
echo "Best picks:" . PHP_EOL . "<br />";
foreach ($heroPicks as $heroName => $pickCount) {
    foreach ($heroVictory as $heroVictoryName => $totalVictory) {
        $total = ($totalVictory * 100) / $pickCount;
    }

    echo $heroName . " - " . $pickCount . PHP_EOL . " - Victorys =  " . $totalVictory . " --  winrate :" . $total . "%" . "<br />";
}


?>
```

[image]

the $result variable  for @bassxzero

[image]

Comment: Can you post what this file looks like `json_decode($file_contents)`

Comment: just edited the post with the new image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer `foreach` will loop through all of your heroes that were picked. This is what you want.

The inner `foreach` is looping through all of your heroes' victories, regardless of the hero the outer loop is currently processing. All the victories are set to 1 because that is how many victories the last hero in your victory array has. This is not what you want.

You don't want a second inner `foreach`. You just want to lookup the victory stats for the hero currently being processed by the outer `foreach`.

```
foreach ($heroPicks as $heroName => $pickCount) {
    $totalVictory = $heroVictory[$heroName] ?? 0;
    $total = ($totalVictory * 100) / $pickCount;

    echo $heroName . " - " . $pickCount . PHP_EOL . " - Victorys =  " . $totalVictory . " --  winrate :" . $total . "%" . "<br />";
}
```